# как улучшить функцию, которая вычисляет сумму трех чисел до суммы четырех (или n) чисел, равных заданному

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Я хочу изменить эту функцию, которая принимает 3 параметра (целевое значение, количество чисел, массив чисел) и вычисляет три числа, сумма которых ближе всего к заданному. Но я делаю это только для 3 чисел. Как сделать так, чтобы это зависело от значения «K».

```
const optimalSum = (t, k, ls) => {

    let result = 0;
    let currentResult = 0;
    let sortArray = ls.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    if (ls.length > k) {
        for (let i = 0; i < sortArray.length - k + 1; i++) {
            let j = i + 1;
            let l = sortArray.length - 1;

            while (j < l) {
                currentResult = sortArray[i] + sortArray[j] + sortArray[l];
                if (currentResult <= t) {
                    result = Math.max(result, currentResult);
                    j++;
                    l--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (currentResult < t) {
                    j++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (currentResult > t) {
                    l--;
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}

optimalSum(174, 3, [51, 56, 58, 59, 61]); // Output must be = 173
optimalSum(163, 3, [50]); // Output must be = 0
optimalSum(163, 3, [50, 55, 56, 57, 58]); // Output must be = 163
optimalSum(230, 3, [91, 74, 73, 85, 73, 81, 87]); // Output must be = 228
```

Comment: Вы написали на "stackoverflow на русском" тут принято задавать вопросы на русском. Исправьте свой вопрос нажав на копку Править или разместите в stackoverflow на английском

Comment: Спасибо большое